# How to integrate a signal in Python

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration, quad

I have to integrate a signal in a range that I decide.

I have used this method:

```
def integrand(x,y):
    return y[x]

result=scipy.integrate.quad(integrand,t0,t1,args=(y))*0.2E-6
```

y is an array of 2500 points in 500microsec. For example t0 is 700 and t1 is 1500.
0.2E-6 is the step between two value of the signal.

Is it correct?

Answer (score 2):

Not really. To integrate a sampled function you can use [`scipy.integrate.simps`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.simps.html) or [`scipy.integrate.trapz`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.trapz.html):

```
result_simps = scipy.integrate.simps(y[t0:t1+1], dx=0.2E-6)
result_trapz = scipy.integrate.trapz(y[t0:t1+1], dx=0.2E-6)
```